# Java - Key catcher

Tags: java, keyboard, key, keylogger

I'm trying to make a kind of a keylogger in Java. I got an app that allowed people to get their RSS feeds on their desktop and I want to make a quick access.
By the way, I need something that can do that:

- I start my java jar file and it minimized in the system tray.
- The user does what he wants to do (Surfing, Watching movies, etc...).
- He pressed a key combination (CTRL + I) and then the java window opens and displays a GUI where he can check for news and modify app configuration.
- Now he can minimize the window (System tray icon) and keep using his computer normaly.

My app has to be totally cross platform. All things are done except this feature.
I've tried to do it with `KeyStroke` and even `System.in` but they only catch key combination when the user has the window as active.

So, is there a way to catch key combination from outside the app (Like a transparent overlay) without using JNI or JNA (That's what my searches gave me).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure your end users would be comfortable with an application that is catching all the keys? I would see this as a security risk.

Comment: This will only catch the two keys of the combination. Nothing more and many apps do that actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to drop to some system dependent library, i.e. use some form of JNI.

The different built-in levels of granularity are:

> `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`
>
> Constant used for registerKeyboardAction that means that the command should be invoked when the receiving component is an ancestor of the focused component or is itself the focused component.
>
> `WHEN_FOCUSED`
>
> Constant used for registerKeyboardAction that means that the command should be invoked when the component has the focus.
>
> `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`
>
> Constant used for registerKeyboardAction that means that the command should be invoked when the receiving component is in the window that has the focus or is itself the focused component

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that possible to make one catcher for each platform, like one JNI file for windows, one for linux and one for mac? I'm not quite good in C++ so is that posssible to make it in C?

Comment: Yes. AFAIK that would be perfectly doable.

Comment: Here's one project targeting Linux: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/  and here's one project targeting windows: http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html

Comment: I've finally solved my problem making differents libraries for each system. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. No operating system worth its salt in today's world will let you just log all keystrokes

Comment: ...but there are plenty of key-loggers for, say Ubuntu. You need to be root of course.

Comment: there are many legitimate uses for logging keystrokes, e.g. global macros